# Load data from database view using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate and want to load a single field from a database view into my model. Here's the situation:

I have one USERS table which has a column called AVATAR_ID. There's also a separate view defined in the database called VIEW_RESOURCES. This view contains an ID and a PATH column. The ID can be matched to the values stored in the AVATAR_ID column.

In SQL I'd be doing the following:

```
select U.ID, U.USERNAME, R.PATH
from USERS U
left join VIEW_RESOURCES R on R.ID = U.AVATAR_ID
where U.ID = ...
```

I've defined the properties of a model in my C# code as follows:

```
public virtual Id { get; protected set; }
public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual string AvatarPath { get; protected set; }
```

I'm using FluentNHibernate for the mapping, which looks like this:

```
Table("USERS");
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");
Map(x => x.UserName).Column("USERNAME").Not.Nullable().Length(256);
```

The code used for loading a single user looks like this:

```
User user = session
.QueryOver<User>()
.Where(x => x.Id == id)
.SingleOrDefault();
```

So far so good, but what I need to know is:

- How to define the mapping for the AvatarPath?
- How to load the PATH column of the VIEW_RESOURCES view into the AvatarPath property of my User object? I'd rather not load it as a separate model which has a relationship to the user. I want it as a property on User, if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could map it as Formula

```
Map(x => x.AvatarPath).Formula("(SELECT R.PATH FROM VIEW_RESOURCES R WHERE R.ID = AVATAR_ID)");
```

other than that you would could make the model and reference private so that it does not go outside